# JavaScript table not displaying properly

Tags: javascript, html

I'm working on a homework for class and I feel like I may just have a simple syntax error of some sort. The table I attempted to create in my JS is not displaying at all in the HTML div called result.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/tfQme.jpg (this is an example output with directions for the assignment)

https://i.stack.imgur.com/9IEPG.jpg (my code being ran in our homework interface upon pressing calculate all inputs disappear and the div results remains empty)

JS

```
function link_events() {  

    document.getElementById("calculate").onclick = calculate;  

}  
function calculate() {  

        var years = document.getElementById('years');
        var population = parseInt(document.getElementById('population').value);
        var rate = parseInt(documet.getElementById('rate').value);

        var table = '' +
                    '<table>' + 
                        '<tr>' + 
                            '<th><strong>Year</strong></th>' +
                            '<th><strong>Population</strong></th>' +
                            '<th><strong>Change</strong></th>' +
                        '</tr>' +
                '';


                var currentYear = 2017;

                for (var i = currentYear; i < (currentYear+years); i++) {
                    var change = (population*rate)/100;
                    population += change;

                    table += '' +
                        '<tr>' + 
                            '<td>' + i + '</td>' +
                            '<td>' + population.toFixed() + '</td>' +
                            '<td>' + change.toFixed() + '</td>' + 
                        '</tr>' +
                    '';
                }

                table += '' +
                    '</table>' +
                '';




                document.getElementById('result').innerHTML = table;
}
```

HTML

```
<!doctype html>  
<META HTTPEQUIV="CACHE-CONTROL" CONTENT="NO-CACHE">  
<meta httpequiv="expires" content="0" />  
<html lang="en">  
<head>  
  <title> hw8 </title>  
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="hw8.css">  
  <script src="hw8.js"></script> 
</head>  
<body>  

<form name="inputform"> 
<div id="input">  

    <h2> Population Growth </h2>  
    Years to forecast: <input type="text" value="<? print $_POST['years']; ?>" name="years"> <br/> <br/>  
    Current Population: <input type="text" value="<? print $_POST['population']; ?>" name="population"> <br/> <br/>  
    Growth Rate: <input type="text" value="<? print $_POST['rate']; ?>" name="rate"> <br/> <br/>  
    <div id="button"> <input type="submit" value="Calculate" id="calculate"> </div> 

</div>  
</form> 

<div id="result"> </div>


</body> 
</html>
```

Comment: Can you show us the result you have insteaf of juste saying "not displaying properly" or provide a plunker ?

Comment: It's not displaying the table at all

Comment: i'll try and upload a screenshot

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is, while you're calling `document.getElementById('population')` for example, you never set the `id` of the input whose name is `population`. Try changing it like this:

```
Current Population: <input type="text" value="<? print $_POST['population']; ?>" name="population" id="population"> <br/> <br/>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you might want to use the html element directly instead of dynamically building a string table. You do this by defining the table element beforehand and then manipulating it from there - its just cleaner.

HTML

```
    <table id='calTable'>
     <tr>
       <th><strong>Year</strong></th>
       <th><strong>Population</strong></th>
       <th><strong>Change</strong></th>
     </tr>
   </table>
```

Javascript

```
 function calculate() {  

     var years = document.getElementById('years');
     var population = parseInt(document.getElementById('population').value);
     var rate = parseInt(documet.getElementById('rate').value);
     var currentYear = 2017;

     for (var i = currentYear; i < (currentYear+years); i++) {
          var change = (population*rate)/100;
          population += change;

          AppendTableCell(i, population, change);

      }
 }


function AppendTableCell(num, population, change)
{
    var row = document.getElementById("calTable").insertRow(0);
    var cell1 = row.insertCell(0);
    var cell2 = row.insertCell(1);
    var cell3 = row.insertCell(2);
    cell1.innerHTML = num;
    cell2.innerHTML = population.toFixed();
    cell3.innerHTML = change.toFixed();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your initial problem is that you never run link_events(); in your main HTML so the onclick event is never assigned to the button.

Under your

```
<div id="result"> </div>
```

add

```
<script>
link_events();
</Script>
```

or just add it to the button directly.

replace this line

```
<div id="button"> <input type="submit" value="Calculate" id="calculate"> </div>
```

with

```
<div>
<button id="calculate" onclick="link_events(); return false;"></button>
</div>
```

Hopefully this will help you to debug a bit further.